# Создание двумерного массива со значениями, введенными в Textbox для вывода в DataGrid WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь заполнить массив значениями, введенными в textbox через функцию Split(). В коде понимаю свою ошибку, но не могу придумать способ её обхода, чтобы можно было использовать введенные значения для создания матрицы и вывода ее в DataGrid...

```
private void Filling_The_Matrix()
    {
        m = int.Parse(mText.Text);
        n = int.Parse(nText.Text);
        int[,] array = new int[m, n];
        string[] matrix1 = new string[int.Parse(MatrixText.Text)]; //Попытка считывания массива из текстбокса (Тут и есть ошибка, ведь я считываю не число, а строку, но как лучше обойти в коде пока не знаю
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) //Заполнение массива значениями
        {
            int[] row = matrix1[i].Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray(); 
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                array[i, j] = row[j];
            }
        }
       
        Dictionary<int, List<string>> model = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) //Заполнение списка данными, введенными в текстбокс
        {
            List<string> matrix = new List<string>();
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                matrix.Add(array[i, j].ToString());
            }
            model.Add(i, matrix);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                // заполнение столбцов грида
                MatrixStart.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn
                {
                    Header = j,
                    Binding = new Binding(String.Format("Value[{0}]", array[i, j]))
                });
            }
            MatrixStart.ItemsSource = model; //Заполнение DataGrid значениями, введенными  в список 
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: 1. Почему не используете привязки, а создание UI через код? 2. Почему именно массив, ведь коллекции куда удобней...?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ 1. Признаться Вам честно, во время работы вообще не задумывался над этим...
2. С коллекциями крайне редко работал, поэтому сделал массив в случае с вводом матрицы

Comment: Стоит задуматься, ведь wpf это привязки и xaml, который вы сейчас благополучно обходите стороной, делая костыли. А коллекции, это аналог массивов, только динамичные, им не надо задавать размеры, вы вон уже ведь пользуетесь Dictionary и List..

Comment: @EvgeniyZ В этом, наверное, и заключается проблема, ибо я в WPF новичок и не знаю всех тонкостей привязки данных, особенно с коллекциями

Comment: А тут вам надо будет поискать, ведь мануалов как грамотно писать WPF проект в интернете (даже тут и даже от меня) полно.